# pgrep pattern length limit

Tags: process, grep

pgrep returns nothing if the pattern length is longer than 15 characters.
I can't find anything in the man page about maximum pattern length.

Is this a bug?

for purposes of exposition I created a process called 12345678901234567890

```
$ pgrep 12345678901234
5367
$ pgrep 123456789012345
5367
$ pgrep 1234567890123456
$
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's not a limit on the pattern length in `pgrep` itself, but a limit on the length of the *comm* (command) field in the /proc/[pid]/stat files (which is where the information in `ps` comes from).

According to `man proc`, the definitions for /proc/[pid]/stat come from /usr/src/linux/fs/proc/array.c so you would need to look there for a definitive answer.

Answer (score 7):

According to the [`pgrep` man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/pgrep.1) (emphasis mine):

> ## Notes
>
> The process name used for matching is limited to the **15 characters present in the output of `/proc/pid/stat`**. Use the `-f` option to match against the complete command line, `/proc/pid/cmdline`.

The reason is that process names are limited to 16 bytes including the NULL termination byte. From [the `prctl` manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/prctl.2.html):

> #### PR_SET_NAME (since Linux 2.6.9)
>
> Set the name of the calling thread, using the value in the location pointed to by `(char *) arg2`. **The name can be up to 16 bytes long, including the terminating null byte**. (If the length of the string, including the terminating null byte, exceeds 16 bytes, the string is silently truncated.)

See [What is the maximum allowed limit on the length of a process name?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23534263/995714)